XRM toolbox not showing custom entities
I'm starting out with XRM Toolbox in order to get info from our D365 ERP.
When I'm logged on, everything works fine and I can see all entities from our Dataverse.
However, when colleagues of mine do the same in XRM, they can connect exactly as I do to our environments but cannot see any of the custom entities.
Even stranger, some can see it in e.g. the production version but not UAT.
Security in Dynamics itself and Powerplatform seem identical so I'm not entirely sure where I have to look.
Anyone has an idea? I'm pretty sure it's a simple security role issue somewhere but after some hours of trying, I rather reacht out to the community ;)
Thank you!

What tool are you using where they can't see custom entities?
I don't see how there is any possibility for it to be anything except security related.  Either they are missing a role in an environment, or the roles are different per environment, or the maybe even the security role is set up so they only have read access to records they own, or in their business unit, and their are no records that meet those criteria.
Just to be sure, you can give them a system admin role temporarily just to prove it is security related or not.

Hi Daryl!
Thanks for your reply.
I'm also convinced it has to be security related but I cant't seem to find out where the security is set. They are all sysadmins in the ERP, but I think it is rather Power platform based. But again, I'm not sure, that's a bit the crux of the question.
I mainly checked with SQL 4 CDS and FetchXML Builder

Is the ERP Dataverse or is that different a different app?  You can manage users and their roles at https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com
